# How to change background color of toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code

```
<label style="margin-top: 2px;margin-right: 13px;" class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" 
onclick="updateGroup(this)" name="screen" value="Profile" actionname="Profile"> 
<i data-swchoff-text="Off" data-swchon-text="On"></i></label>
```

I want to change the background color as blue and text as white when toggle button is "ON" and Background color as white and text color as black when toggle button is "OFF"

Comment: `@Sowjanya` You can achieve by css only without using JS or jQuery so you need to use **input[type="checkbox"]:checked~i{ write here what you need }**. and from `:after` and `:before` to set text **Off** and **On**.

Answer (score 1):

I used `:checked` property with `tilde(~)` operator to set `background & text` color on toggle.

```css
.toggle{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.toggle input{opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0}
.toggle i{
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  height: 34px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-style: normal;
  transition: 350ms;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.toggle input:checked ~ i{
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.toggle i:before{
  content: attr(data-swchoff-text);
}
.toggle input:checked ~ i:before{
  content: attr(data-swchon-text);
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" name="screen" value="Profile" actionname="Profile">
  <i data-swchoff-text="Off" data-swchon-text="On"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: You might want to remove the inline event listener.

Comment: `connexo` Thanks, I have removed inline event listener.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't change inline style directly**, the **best solution** is creating **css classes** for **ON** & **OFF** state and toggle class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name=theme]').change(function(e) {
    $('#MainContent').toggleClass('light-theme dark-theme');
  });
});
```

```css
.theme {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.theme.dark-theme {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.theme.light-theme {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<label style="margin-top: 2px;margin-right: 13px;" class="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" name="theme" /> 
Blue Theme
</label>

<div id="MainContent" class="theme light-theme">

  <div id="artical">
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info <br />
    More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info 
    More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info  <br />
    More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info 
    More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info  <br />
    More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info More Info 
  </div>
  
</div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The correct solution doesn't require any Javascript at all.

Comment: I understand form the question that you want to change another DIV not the same button

Comment: this's the solution if you need to change another div